# How can I tranform this String?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to alter this string: `NC_037078 1:122545 124035` into this: `NC_037078.1:122545-124035` but I don´t know how.

The document is like this:\

```
    1. rrn16 \
16S ribosomal RNA [Genlisea aurea]\
Other Aliases: C7J69_pgr001, BK572_Gau_0120\
Genomic context: Chloroplast\
Annotation:  NC_037078.1 (122545..124035, complement)\
ID:` 36166080
```

The script until now looks like this:

```
code=$(ls -l | grep "Annotation" data.txt | cut -d " " -f3,4 | sed 's/[(]/:/g' | sed 's/[)]/ /g' | sed 's/[,]/ /g' | sed 's/[ ]//g' | sed 's/["."]/ /g' )
```

Can you help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`echo NC_037078 1:122545 124035 | sed 's/ /./1' | sed 's/ /:/g'`

Note:
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047776/sed-replace-only-first-occurrence-then-only-second-occurrence-then-only-third